# AWS CLI VERSION UPGRADE

Tags: amazon-web-services, version, aws-cli, sudo

I have installed AWS CLI latest version using "sudo pip install --upgrade awscli " .
this has successfully updated my aws cli version but for only root users, but for all remaining users , it is showing version as previous one only, If I run the command without sudo then its saying permission denied.

If my server has multiple linux users and want to update my aws cli version from 1.16.3 to 1.18.223 for all users, how can I do it ?

Please help me .

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the path where you want to install, the binary.

[Install the AWS CLI version 1 using the bundled installer with sudo](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux.html#install-linux-bundled)

```
curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle-1.18.223.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
unzip awscli-bundle.zip
sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

Just curious when you are upgrading the `AWS Cli` why not the latest which is backward compatible and probaly more options

Try not to install pip packages with `sudo`. Better use a [Creating virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

Comment: Helo @samtoddler, thanks for the comment but I am not so sure on adjusting the path to make it available for all users, can you pls guide me more detailed on that .  I followed the same aws doc " https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux.html#install-linux-bundled " where to change the installation path and also which path to choose to make it available for every user.

Comment: I have a python error aswell , which I am unable to understand . 
error: 

 ImportError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FILES_COMMAND'